# How to get correct file path after uploading using fileInput using R shiny?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a code that uploads a file. After uploading the file using a action button "Save to Database", I store the file name and file path in vectors.

In the same app, I have another tab that displays the excel output in form of table. So, to read the file I use the file path retrieved while saving the file using the action button.

The problem is I get "File does not exist" since the path is something like below

"C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpINivvL/69ff834f0b2623ef2ec95c41/0.xlsx"

While the location I uploaded the file from is

" "D:/Data_Dump/summary.xlsx"

How to solve this issue?

```
UI.R code

tabItem(tabName = "file",
              mainPanel(
                titlePanel(h2("Upload your XLSX file here ")), fluidRow(
                  column(6,
                         fileInput('file1', 'Choose a XLSX file to upload',
                                   accept = c('.xlsx'))),
                  column(6,actionButton("save","Save to Database")),
                  div(DT::dataTableOutput("contents"),style = "font-size: 100%;width: 150%")
                )

              )
      )

server.R code

eventReactive(input$save,{

    filenm <- input$file1
    filenm$name



    tablelist <<- c(tablelist,as.character(filenm$name))
    print(tablelist)
    filePath <<- c(filePath,as.character(filenm$datapath))
    print(filePath)

    return (tablelist)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

one workaround for getting the actual filepath, might be using the `shinyFiles` package. But you have to ensure the upload functionality by something like `file.copy()` manually. In addition in `shinyFiles` you cannot specify a certain filetype to be accepted.

Anyway here is a small example of `shinyFiles`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                   title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL),

  textOutput("txt_file")     
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  tablelist<-NULL
  filePath<<-NULL
  volumes = getVolumes()
  observe({  
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)

    if(!is.null(input$Btn_GetFile)){
       browser()
      file_selected<-parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
      #check if file extension is .xlsx 
      tablelist <<- c(tablelist,as.character(file_selected$name))
      print(tablelist)
      filePath <<- c(filePath,as.character(file_selected$datapath))
      print(filePath)
      #upload file via e.g. file.copy()
      output$txt_file <- renderText(as.character(file_selected$datapath))
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```